# Git error while trying to install Active Admin from Github

Tags: github, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

Everything was working until I installed the Active Admin get with the settings.

This is what happens when I run bundle install:

```
Fetching git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.129]: errno=Operation timed out

Git error: command `git clone 'git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git'
"/Users/Kenneth/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/cache/bundler/git/active_admin-d67faab65e9b74efbc8efb4a777a851e9f78b2ca"
--bare --no-hardlinks` in directory /Users/Kenneth/Desktop/U2K has failed
```

My Gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '4.0.1' 
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.0.3.0'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.1.1'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'


group :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
 gem 'pg'
 gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

Thanks

Comment: You're getting a timeout on `git clone 'git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git` -- are you blocked from SSH outbound to `github.com`?

Comment: @joe I would not know now to check if I am blocked from SSH outbound to github.com. How do I check?

Comment: Can you get to `https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin`?

Comment: @joe yes I can get to [link] (https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin)

Answer (score 0):

try in terminal first to exlcude any issue with bundler, but your issues seems intermittent with github connection.

```
$ git clone 'git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git
```

secondly, try a specific commit - like

```
gem 'activeadmin',  github: 'gregbell/active_admin' , :ref => '2c1a16368fd5fb8122329eb61c848bbd0e516870'
```